# BIRT Report : first report very slow

Tags: birt

I have a problem: First of all, my application is working properly, my reports are well generated.
Now I have a little concern about the 1st report generated that puts more than 45s.
Subsequently, if I run the same report or any other report, it is done in 2-3 seconds.

Do you have any idea to solve this problem for the 1st report?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, initialization takes most of the time.
You'll have to figure out what part of the initialization.
I think you'll have to add logging with timestamp at several places in the code or profiling to see how long each part takes
1) Starting up the Java process and loading the BIRT classes
2) Starting up the BIRT report engine
3) Loading ressouces inside the report (e.g. JS files and libraries)
4) Connecting to the DB (in particular, if you are using connection pooling)
5) DB initialization (often the DB caches data very efficiently, so subsequenct SQL statements selecting the same or similar data can run *very* fast)

For example, you could add log statements inside the initialization event of the report itself, inside the beforeOpen and afterOpen events of the Data Source, inside the beforeOpen and afterOpen events of the Data Sets, and inside your Java code calling the reports.